# Product overlapping in search catalog

Tags: css, magento

We are using Magento content management, but I still cannot seem to fix this overlapping issue.  When searching for a product, the results will display below; however, some products will overlap each other, making it impossible for the user to view ALL possible results.  It does not happen on every page, just on specific searched items ([like this particular one](http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=0&q=800ps)).  I have tried searching through the CSS code and the Magento content management system settings for a possible solution, but I am clearly stumped.

Can someone help me, please?

Here is a screenshot:
http://imgur.com/PVUSPi8

---

Comment: Can you posta screenshot perhaps, and code you used.

Comment: Just stick to the technical details. We don't need to know company drama. But we do need to see your code.

Comment: @JGallardo thanks for the warning.  I have removed it.  I also forgot to mention the reasoning is based behind the fact that I am still a novice at web development.  I know software development, but not quite web.  I have been searching up and down for the theme.css file through ftp, but it is lost in a lot of useless files that I need to sort out and organize.

I would also post a screenshot; however, I am still new on _this_ account, so I am unable to post any screenshots until I have been around a little long.

Comment: @DragonDaime while you are new, you can share images with [imgur](http://imgur.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overlapping issue was resolved after I reindexed the data.

Magento Admin > System > Index Management

Comment: Great, but I still think you should apply my code changes below - for a more fool-proof way of outputting the grid.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give it a whirl.
I appreciate you helping me. =]

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Just wow. That code is a mess. Basically all you need to do is remove garbage CSS.

In the unordered list, remove all inline CSS, making this:

```
<ul class="products-grid first last odd" style="position: relative; height: 1106px;">
```

into this

```
<ul class="products-grid first last odd">
```

And for each item outputted inside a `<LI>`-tag you also need to remove all inline CSS, making lines like these:

```
<li class="item last item-col-0" style="position: absolute; width: 235px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
```

look like this instead

```
    <li class="item last item-col-0">
```

That goes for those `<LI>`-tags inside `<STRONG>`too, remove all inline styling.

After that edit file: `/skin/frontend/default/galaelectronues/css/styles.css` and replace line 703 with this:

```
.products-grid li.item { float: right; width: 235px; padding: 0px 20px 20px; }
```

All done!

**EDIT**

IT's worse then I thought... It's JS that does all that inline styling inside the file `/skin/frontend/default/galaelectronues/js/galaelectronues.js`.

You could try removing everything between lines 37-67, leaving the function empty.  But even if that doesn't work, that JS file is your problem.  Changing the CSS on line 703 as mentioned above, and figuring out how to clean up the galaelectronues.js file is what you need to do.

Comment: The `<li>` should not have so many classes in there. The styles should be inherited.

Comment: That's pure opinion, and has nothing to do with the solution I provided - nor is it what's causing the problem.

Comment: I am not saying that your solution is not valid, I was just adding a general observation. Anyone new to web development should be warned not to have inline styles, nor classes directly in the `<li>` as it will end up bloating the CSS file.